# Website menu displays funny in all IE before IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, xhtml, cross-browser

I am new to CSS and have coded my first site with CSS. I will admit to not fully understanding CSS yet but would like to learn. I have heard about special XHTML & CSS coding being needed for older IE browsers but really don't know what CSS code is causing the trouble.

The website is [here](http://www.wavelake.ca). The problem is with the top and bottom navigation menus on all pages except Blog and Moodle (I haven't updated those yet). Can someone help me with what needs to be isolated for IE?

Thanks so much!

Comment: More description of "the problem" is needed. For more info about IE and CSS, try these: http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/internet-explorer-7.shtml and http://www.google.com.au/search?q=css+ie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do three things.

1. use a strict doctype at the top of your page. at the moment you have transitional. a strict doctype ensures that IE conforms to CSS standards the best it can.
2. Add the following bit of CSS for your top navigation list items

   `#topnavcontainer ul li { display:inline; }`
3. Add the following bit of CSS for your bottom navigation list items

   `#bottomnavcontainer ul li { display:inline; }`

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

strict doctype

Comment: "a strict doctype ensures that IE conforms to CSS standards the best it can" - Not really: as long as you have a valid `doctype` that doesn't trigger quirk mode it should be fine

Comment: Thank you very much for this response. I added the strict to the DOCTYPE on just my index page as a test. I also added the extra suggested line to the CSS. I uploaded a test and it seems the CSS did the trick. All the pages now work properly even though only the index was updated with the strict DOCTYPE. I will however go back and do the DOCTYPE update to the other pages. Thanks again for the response. Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (that should work regardless of doctype);

```
#topnavcontainer li {
    display:inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}
```

The short explanation is that `inline-block` allow you to style the list-items as if they were block level elements (ie, give them width, height, etc) while still laying them out inline. An advantage over `float: left` is that you can apply text-align to `#topnavcontainer` to align your navigation left/center/right. You can also set vertical alignment although that seems to be a bit finicky at times.

The other two lines, `zoom` and `*display` are a trick to make this work in older versions of IE. It's a long explanation but if you want to know more about it, search Google for "hasLayout" and "css star hack".